# Pandas_datareader failed to read symbol (random symbols)

Tags: pandas, pandas-datareader

This function I'm using in a module was working perfectly for months, now I'm suddenly getting a bunch of random errors -- enough to require a try except block.  Why does is it not finding these symbols on some runs?

Anything I can do to resolve this -- just looking for consistency here.
Some of these are clearly valid tickers that are rejecting -- LULU, HD, SAP, DG for example.

```
#Dataset for this day -- 
l = ['AAPL', 'PLUG', 'MSFT', 'PENN', 'EBAY', 'GFI', 'ATVI', 'AMAT', 'TSM', 'MRVL', 'SE', 'CRM', 'LLY', 'ABB', 'DHI', 'FAST', 'MAS', 'CDNS', 'TBIO', 'GIS', 'IMMU', 'HD', 'STM', 'NUAN', 'LAKE', 'DT', 'HOLX', 'DG', 'BLDP', 'ADBE', 'OSTK', 'AU', 'BMRN', 'KNX', 'BJ', 'ADI', 'ADSK', 'PAAS', 'AHPI', 'CLX', 'LRCX', 'DLR', 'MKC', 'TEAM', 'INSM', 'A', 'SWKS', 'CLGX', 'CCI', 'CTXS', 'CMC', 'LULU', 'CMI', 'LSCC', 'WGO', 'VRTX', 'PRTS', 'KLAC', 'FTNT', 'TREX', 'ENTG', 'TAL', 'MNTA', 'DXCM', 'HALO', 'NBIX', 'IIVI', 'AVEO', 'EBS', 'SGEN', 'AMKR', 'THO', 'TSCO', 'RMD', 'REGN', 'ALNY', 'QDEL', 'CHTR', 'OTEX', 'WERN', 'BKI', 'ADPT', 'BLK', 'SNPS', 'WSM', 'FORM', 'AMRC', 'ILMN', 'MCO', 'CGEN', 'MOH', 'NTES', 'ROK', 'PEGA', 'SPY', 'NVDA', 'NEM', 'LOW', 'GLUU', 'SAP']

def get_returns(symbol,lookback=1):
    '''Helper function to calculate returns based on csv'''
    start = dt.datetime(2020,6,1)                        #Previously was JUST 2020
    try:
        df = pdr.DataReader(symbol,'yahoo',start) #.drop(columns=['Volume','Open','High','Low'])
        pct = df.Close.pct_change(lookback).tail(1).values[0]
    except:
        print('Error calling pdr with ',symbol)
        pct = 0
    return pct

#Example of the implementation...
total = 0
for i in l:
    ret = get_returns(i)
    total += ret
```

I've tried using dt.datetime() as start object, but initially I just used the current year (2020).  Each time I run it, I'm getting different errors.

Here's my current run (on SAME symbols list)

```
Error calling pdr with  DG
Error calling pdr with  BLDP
Error calling pdr with  AU
Error calling pdr with  DLR
Error calling pdr with  CLGX
Error calling pdr with  LULU
```

Here's prior call...

```
Error calling pdr with  HD
Error calling pdr with  DG
Error calling pdr with  BLDP
Error calling pdr with  AU
Error calling pdr with  CLGX
Error calling pdr with  LULU
Error calling pdr with  SAP
Error calling pdr with  NYT
```